# Upgrading Unrevoked Desire from Eclair to Froyo

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, 2.1-eclair, ota-update, root-access

I'm currently running my HTC Desire on 2.1 (O2 branded from the UK, if it makes a difference) which has been rooted via [Unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/unrevoked3). I've just now been prompted to upgrade it to what I assume is 2.2 via an OTA update. I'd quite like to do this but I'm assuming this will cause me to lose my root. Unrevoked seems to now say it supports 2.2 as well as 2.1 so would it just be a matter of doing the OTA update and re-rooting with Unrevoked?

Also, I've never performed an upgrade before, do I lose all my apps/data/configs? How long does it normally take?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a standard OTA update then you shouldn't lose anything at all, and the update should take less than half an hour, just make sure that your battery is fully charged before you start. All your apps, data and configuration should stay. The only exception to this is where things have changed between Eclair and Froyo, so some of your apps may not be compatible with Froyo (though it's been out long enough now that's very unlikely).

Yes, you will lose your root status, but should be able to root again afterwards, provided your chosen root method works on Froyo, or you can find a different rooter that will work if not.

Comment: I'm pretty confident unrevoked will let me root again on 2.2. So OTA seems pretty appealing. I'll be fully charged and doing it over WIFI but thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend leaving the OTA update. Instead, download and install a custom pre-rooted 2.2 ROM.

[This one from MoDaCo](http://android.modaco.com/content/htc-desire-desire-modaco-com/317191/22-oct-r9-with-sense-modaco-custom-rom-for-htc-desire-with-online-kitchen-2-2-froyo/) would be a good choice. Alternatively, check out some of the options on the XDA Forums or consider Cyanogenmod if you aren't so attached to HTC's Sense overlay and would like something closer to 'stock' Android.

You shouldn't lose anything with the MoDaCo ROM, though I found I needed to wipe if switching between Sense and non-Sense ROMs. Check out Titanium Backup if you would like to make restoring your apps easy and always do a Nandroid backup before flashing a new ROM.

If you haven't already, download the ROM Manager app from the market to make flashing ROMs and managing back ups a breeze!

Comment: I suppose my concern about flashing another ROM is that I will have to set up all my apps/configuration again. Or am I incorrect on this?

Comment: @michael You really shouldn't lose anything unless you want to switch to a non-Sense ROM. I'd really recommend going with the MoDaCo ROM if you want to stick with something close to the official HTC Sense ROM (just has a few performance improvements and customisation options). But back everything up first and you should be fine in any case. Go for it! ;)

Comment: It does look rather tempting. And having reread the thread carefully I see it does indeed say no wipe is required. Guess i'll be giving this a go tonight!

Comment: Well that's not gone so well. Followed the instructions at modaco and now i'm stuck on the carrier logo and can't get past it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @michael Bummer! Were you able to get back to recovery (hold volume down when you power on the phone, use volume to highlight 'recovery', power button to select)? You could try wiping your Dalvik-cache from recovery, that helped me before. Otherwise you might need to backup with Titanium, wipe, reflash then restore. I don't think it's too much hassle so as not to be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

@michael.jefferys use Titanium backup to backup all of your apps and their data when switching to a new rom.